# jQuery iviewer drag features is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to bring the zoom feature on bootstrap modal popup.Except dragging feature everything works fine. I tried many possibilities. But nothing helps to get it.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="pdfModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="UploadTitle">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="material-icons" >close </i></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="ViewUploadTitle"> <!--<i class="material-icons"> folder_open</i> --> View Image</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="min-height:400px; height: calc(100% - 120px); ">          
           <div id="ImagePreview" class="ImagePreview" > </div>   </div>

          <div class="row" id="DisplayUploadNote">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><?php echo _("Close"); ?></button>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery program

```
 var iv1 = $("#ImagePreview").
            width($(window).width() - 80).
            height($(window).height()-80).iviewer({
                   src: '<?php  echo get_url().'view-uploads?vw='; ?>'+UploadFAid+customer_id
              });
    iv1.iviewer('loadImage', '<?php  echo get_url().'view-uploads?vw='; ?>'+UploadFAid+customer_id);
```

and one more program as well.

```
  var iv1 = $("#ImagePreview").iviewer({
                   src: '<?php  echo get_url().'view-uploads?vw='; ?>'+UploadFAid+customer_id,   
                   update_on_resize: true,
                   zoom_animation: true,
                   zoom_min: 20,

                   mousewheel: true,
                   onMouseMove: function(ev, coords) { },
                   onStartDrag: function(ev, coords) { return true; }, //this image will not be dragged
                   onDrag: function(ev, coords) { }
              });
    iv1.iviewer('loadImage', '<?php  echo get_url().'view-uploads?vw='; ?>'+UploadFAid+customer_id);
```

Here `onStartDrag` I tried both true and false. Both didnt give me results.

Comment: any answer or suggestion regarding this